# How to access element with custom attribute using Watir?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, watir

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<input custom_attribute="so cool" type="text" />
```

I would like to enter text in it using [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
browser.text_field(:xpath , "//input[@custom_attribute='so cool']/").set("even more cool")
```

Sources:

- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/XPath
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/2007/01/29/watir-select-element-using-custom-attribute/

Answer (score 7):

Filipin's answer did not work for my job with watir-webdriver.

I did, however, find a way to do the job with css selectors.

```
browser.element(:css, "input[custom_attribute='so cool']").send_keys("the coolest")
```